# Broken pages using Tomcat with HTTP/2 on Redhat Linux 2.6.32

Tags: linux, redhat, http2, tomcat8.5

I'm getting broken pages, that is pages not loading completely (eg. missing images, styles, js etc).

I'm using Tomcat 8.5, on Redhat Linux 2.6.32.

I found that if I comment out the line below from `server.conf` it works fine

```
 <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
```

I suspect its a resource issue but cant seem to find any errors or know where to look.

Comment: Are the images, styles and is on the same domain as the main page? Or a different domain that resolves to same server (e.g. static.example.com)?

Comment: @BarryPollard on some domain

Comment: Can you add the HTTP2 session logs from chrome://net-internals/#events please?

Comment: @BarryPollard unfortunately the issue was happening in a production environment, we had to turn off http/2 so I cant reproduce the issue at the present moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the issue was with the Firefox v53 client we were using